# I want to invoke Samsung Pass SDK (fingerprint) from an HCE service when the phone is locked

Tags: android, fingerprint, hce

I'm developing a payments application and I would like to use the samsung fingerprint technology and the HCE feature at the same time but I don't want to have the screen unlocked to save time when paying.

Is it possible to invoke the Pass Samsung fingerprint SDK, retrieve the Unique ID, sign the transaction with it and return it to the HCE reader ?